# Angular - How to disable particular date in Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to disable Monday from "mat-datepicker". So here is my code in the class component.

```
  dateFilter = (_date: any) =>{
    let day = _date.getDay();
    console.log(day);
    
    return day != 1;
  }
```

And in my template file :

```
 <input [matDatepicker]="picker" [matDatepickerFilter]="dateFilter" />
 <mat-datepicker (closed)="ClosePicker($event)" #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

But now after implementing this, I can't see any date on my calendar. And in the months section, I just see "February" available there. No other months are showing. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am willing to share more code if needed.

Comment: Can you please try `const day = (_date || new Date()).getDay();
    return day !== 1` inside your filter.

Comment: Man it removes year also, Now I'm just seeing only one month and only one year.

Comment: Could you provide a stackblitz link with your problem? I am getting no issue as such

Comment: see write `dateFilter = (_date: any|null):boolean=>...`. Should be work. See if you has an error in console. This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s836tn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-filter-example.ts) work

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Min max function to select and disable certain date periord

By using Angular Material

```
<mat-form-field style="width:130px;" appearance="fill">
                        <input style="position: relative;top: -7px;" [min]="nestedMinDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker3"
                          [(ngModel)]="nestedReorder.PromiseDate"
                          (change)="dateFormating(nestedReorder.PromiseDate,i,j)">
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker #picker3></mat-datepicker>
                      </mat-form-field>
```

Type Script Code

```
this.minDate= formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en');
```